# return by value function optimization

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

Sample Function 1

```
int func1 (int arg)  
{  
   return arg + 10;  
}
```

Sample Function 2

```
int func1 (int arg)  
{  
   int retval = arg + 10;  
   return retval;  

}
```

```
func_xyz (int x);  

int main ()  
{  
int a = 10;  
int p = func1 (a);  

func_xyz(p);  
}
```

**Is there any difference between runtime behaviour of these functions (sample 1 and sample 2)?**

I have a function definition in my code that uses sample 1 style function definition. When i invoke this function, a million times (not reproducable for lesser iterations) and try to pass this value to `func_xyz`, i get a `segfault`. However, when i use sample 2 style definition, `segfault` goes away. But i am unable to understand the reason for this behavior.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: what if he is trying to ask which is more effecient or a better practise?

Comment: @PigBen - nice psychic answer! (There's not a badge for that one though!)

Comment: With an optimising compiler, probably no difference.

Comment: @lava, search the web for "return value optimization C++".

Comment: @lava : return back and tell whether we guessed your question correctly or not??

Comment: @Mac:  Very true.  But I see no harm in adopting habits that need less optimization by default.

Comment: Sorry guys, the actual question was lost in indentation.

Comment: @ayush:  In that case, the latter would be a better choice because it uses less code than the former.  It may just be me, but I get annoyed when I see code that has declared useless variables just to store a value in once and then use later.

Comment: @PigBen: wholeheartedly agreed. I'd never write option 2 myself, because it's more work than is needed, for both myself and the compiler. That said, in terms of run-time performance, there should be no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in **THEORY** in function2 a local variable will be initiated (which will take just a bit more space),  then the calculation will be calculated and value will be copied to the variable's location.
After that the copy will be copied to the return value. So that's an extra copy operation.

in **REALITY** compilers do that optimization in compile time, and remove unneeded variables if their value isn't actually used. (refactoring)

Comment: Mightn't `return arg + 10;` also implicitly use a local variable to store the result of `arg + 10` before returning?  I don't mean anything fancy by this, just that the assembly for both might look like `add r1, 10; //r1 + 10 not returned directly!`  `ret r1;`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some details about the [return value optimization in compilers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization).

Try with a class that has a non-trivial copy constructor to see what is actually happening.

Answer (score 0):

There is absolutely no difference. Any compiler can see that the code is just

int main()
{
   func_xyz(20);
}

What does the called function do??